# Including files in index.php (Fat-Free Framework)

Tags: php, include, fat-free-framework

I want to include two files (`routes.php` and `globals.php`) in `index.php` (Fat Free Framework), but I don't know how.

I have tried require and include the Fat Free way:

```
$f3=require('lib/base.php');

$f3=require('app/globals.php'); 
$f3=require('app/routes.php');

$f3=include('app/globals.php');
$f3=include('app/routes.php');
```

and then just normal PHP:

```
require 'app/globals.php';
require 'app/routes.php';
```

but it does not work.

This works:

```
$f3->config('app/globals.cfg');
$f3->config('app/routes.cfg');
```

but I do not want to use `.cfg` files, just `.php`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the problem with `cfg` files?

Comment: You don't have to overwrite the `$f3` variable each time you require/include a new script. `require('app/globals.php');` is enough.

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on "it does not work"?

Comment: What do you want to include? PHP Class files or config files? for php classes use the AUTOLOAD var and set it to `app/`.

Comment: You can use .php instead of .cfg just fine with nothing more than renaming the file to .php. I have one like...
$f3->config('app/adminconfig.php');

Answer (score 2):

If you are afraid of serving your .cfg or .ini files to the clients browser, you can simply forbid that in the shipped .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.cfg 
RewriteRule \.cfg$ - [R=404]
```

Answer (score 0):

## File and class inclusion

The Fat Free Way of including files [is to use `AUTOLOAD`](http://trickforexs.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/f3-autoloader.html).  This can be done in two ways:

(a) setting the `AUTOLOAD` variable in `index.php`:

```
$f3->set('AUTOLOAD', 'relativepathfromindex/routes.php; relativepathfromindexpath/globals.php');
```

(b) adding the `AUTOLOAD` variable [to the `config.ini` file](http://takacsmark.com/fat-free-php-framework-tutorial-4-database-models-crud/):

```
AUTOLOAD=relativepathfromindex/routes.php; relativepathfromindexpath/globals.php
```

then ensuring the `config.ini` file is referenced in `index.php`:

```
$f3->config('config.ini');
```

This is a great way to include all controllers for example in one go by adding something like the following to the `config.ini`:

```
AUTOLOAD=controllers/
```

## Globals

From your file names however you appear to perhaps be using globals, which may include something like:

```
define("LOGLEVEL", "DEBUG");
```

The Fat Free Framework [does not support this syntax](http://fatfreeframework.com/framework-variables), so use the same method described above using either a set in `index.php` (Fat Free recommends switching to CamelCase):

```
$f3->set('logLevel', 'DEBUG');
```

or adding it to `config.ini`:

```
logLevel=DEBUG
```

## Routes

If you want to reference routes outside `index.php`, you will have to amend something like the following:

```
$f3->route('GET /@controller/@action','@controller->@action');
```

to [a different format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442008/fat-free-framework-global-variables-and-functions#20466097) as you probably won't have `$f3` declared:

```
Base::instance()->route('GET /@controller/@action','@controller->@action');
```